# Can't get string informations from another intent

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult

I searched a lot and tried things but the onActivityResult function isn't launched when the intent from which I try to get a string information is closed.

I use Visual Studio to write this application, this is my code :

The click event that opens the activity where users can type strings :

```
    private void Btn_Valid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       ----
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(activity_OF_TransfertChxChmb));
            StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
       ----
    }
```

The function in the openned Intent that should return the string information :

```
    private void Validate()
    {
        string stringToPassBack = tb_Store.Text;

        // put the String to pass back into an Intent and close this activity
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.PutExtra("result", stringToPassBack);
        SetResult(Result.Ok, intent);
        Finish();

    }
```

And the onActivityResult function that should be launched in the first activity:

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.onActivityResult(requestCode, 0, data);

        if (requestCode == 0)
        {
            if (resultCode == -1) // Ok
            {
                string result = data.GetStringExtra("result");
            }
            if (resultCode == 0) // Canceled
            {
                //Write your code if there's no result
            }
        }
    }
```

I am missing something, but can't figure out what.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the extra via:

```
intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, stringToPassBack);
```

Your key is `Intent.ExtraText`.

You are retrieving the extra via:

```
string result = data.GetStringExtra("result");
```

Your key is `"result"`.

So, perhaps `Intent.ExtraText` does not equal `"result"`. You need to use the same key in both places.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I tried to change with : intent.PutExtra("result", stringToPassBack);   but the event isn't launched